# How to export data from oracle 11g to .dmp file using java(netbeans)?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

First , I have created a file chooser to select my destination where I have to store my dmp file. Next I used runtime to create the dump file but I get a negative message. I am not sure what is wrong in my code.

```
 JFileChooser f = new JFileChooser()       
 f.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY); 
 f.showSaveDialog(null);    

 path=f.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
 path=path+"\\";
 path=path.replace("\\","/");
 path=path+o;
 Process p=null;
 Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime(); 
 p=runtime.exec("exp username/passcode@localhost file="+path+".dmp");
  int pr=p.waitFor();
    if(pr==0){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup Process Successfully Done");
    }else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Backup Process Ended Unsuccessfully"); 
    }
```

Comment: "*but I get a negative message*" - and what *is* the **exact** error message? **[Edit]** your question and add the message (do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact problem is here, but _a_ problem is that `Runtime.exec()` will stall if the process produces output, and nothing is available to consume that output. There's loads of information about using `exec()` properly, on StackOverflow and elsewhere.